# node-orm sync to Alter Tables (similar to DataMapper.auto_upgrade)

Tags: node.js, orm, coffeescript

I'm using node-orm to try to setup my database. Here is the model code.

```
db = orm.connect("mysql", client, (success, db) ->
  Strain = db.define("strain",
    name:
      type: "string"
      validations: [ orm.validators.unique() ]
    old_body:
      type: "string"
    body:
      type: "string"
    created_at:
      type: "date"
    update_at:
      type: "date"
  )
  Strain.sync()
)
```

I changed the /orm/lib/databases/mysql.js file to console.log the returned Sync info.

```
this._client.query(_query, function (err, info) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(info);
  console.log("collection synced");
});
```

The first time Strain.sync() runs, this is the output.

```
null

{ affectedRows: 0,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  setMaxListeners: [Function],
  emit: [Function],
  addListener: [Function],
  on: [Function],
  once: [Function],
  removeListener: [Function],
  removeAllListeners: [Function],
  listeners: [Function] }

collection synced
```

Now the table is created as it should be. When I restart the server and run Strain.sync() again, this is the output:

```
null

{ affectedRows: 0,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 1,
  message: '',
  setMaxListeners: [Function],
  emit: [Function],
  addListener: [Function],
  on: [Function],
  once: [Function],
  removeListener: [Function],
  removeAllListeners: [Function],
  listeners: [Function] }

collection synced
```

The warning count jumped to "1", but err is null, and message is empty.

I need to figure out how I can change the model and add a new property, like "deleted_at", and update the table WITHOUT losing data. I know I can do Strain.sync( force: true ), but that will drop the table then re-create it. I'm just looking to update the table, similar to DataMapper's auto_upgrade function.

Is there any way to do this with node-orm, or any ORM that works with nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the current version of sync() only creates tables, does not update.

> Note: sync() only creates tables at the moment; table modifications will be added in an upcoming version.

https://github.com/dresende/node-orm#creating-the-model-on-the-database